# Invoking Http Request In Java

Tags: java, http

I have standalone, swing based application, that allows the user to enter any URL and it returns the status code.

I want to let the user to enter any URL that works when he uses the same URL in a browser, no matter what the URL is (e.g. parameters with special characters, json strings, etc.).

How can I implement that?

I tried to use URL class, but in some cases, I saw that one web site did not accept a json string I gave, although it was accepted when I copy the URL to the browser.

Comment: Did you check the list which popped after you entered the question's title? It's the same list as you see in the "Related" section in the right hand side.

Comment: OK, here is an example:
http://my.computer.com/input?json={"ID":"123456", "data":{"st":"1.1","application":"google","action":"query"}}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the java.net.URI object.  Some of the constructors will properly escape extended characters.

[URI(String scheme,
           String authority,
           String path,
           String query,
           String fragment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Even so, you'll need to carefully encode the query string to make sure the JSON doesn't spill over into other parameters if there are & characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked for me:

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```